# How to understand "run it 5 times" in ResNet paper?

Tags: deep-learning, resnet

In [Resnet paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03385), the authors said "run it 5 times"  in the caption of Table 6 to report some results. How is it done? It it to train the model 5 times, or test 5 times with the same set of model parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they reference a standard evaluation mode in CNN. The input image is of size 256x256, but the network input is 224x224. Thus, you sample five 224x224 images from image center and corners. Then you classify all of them and select mean response or maximum.